# AppStore: will app relying on network be approved?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I develop a well-looking professionally designed application, which loads events for some clubs at startup (it has more functionality, but all require network connection).

If there's no internet access, app shows "Error: No network access" message with OK button. It exits when user presses this button.

Will it be accepted in App Store? If no, what should I change?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an opinion question, but my experiences suggest:

1. It's OK that your app requires network access to provide meaningful content.
2. Do NOT forcibly terminate (`exit`) your app in this case, but instead show a helpful message, and keep polling the network status (ie use something like Reachability). If and when the network connectivity comes back, remove the message and proceed.

Bonus points: If you can cache data from when there *is* a connection, then you can run the app anyway showing the most recent data you have. This is generally preferable as a user experience to simply blocking access to the UI if you can't get to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Do not exit the application.

If your app work only if network is available, that's okay. But if network is not there, it would be better if you show an empty view with proper message (That for this app, network is needed or something like that. Add some error images or graphics it'll improve the user experience also). Don't forcefully close the app, it can be consider as a crash(Apple will reject your app).